# Azure function: Multiple time triggers

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have a function that get data from different APIs and then perform some operations (exactly the same for each one). I want to perform this in different time interval for each data in Azure functions (for example I want to download one data every 10 seconds and one data every 2 days). Is it possible to handle this in one function or I should create separated function for each API?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to handle using a single function but as Timer Triggered functions work on singleton mechanism and they use blob leases to maintain this singularity. If a function invocation cannot acquire a blob lease means that another function already running and this function invocation won't trigger, so having a short period like 10 seconds will be tricky to achieve. Please go through [this document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger) for additional details.
Just so that you are aware. Timer triggered functions acquire blob leases based on their host ID which by default is acquired by truncating the first 32 characters of the host name, if the these Host ID's are same for your functions they might compete for the same blob lease. You can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2015) here for additional details.